# What is the difference between `remote.<name>.push` and `push.default`?

Tags: git

What is the difference between `remote.<name>.push` and `push.default`?

Do they both specify the default `refspec` argument to `git push`?

If yes, what is the precedence order between them?

Does `remote.<name>.push` apply to specific remote repository `<name>`, while `push.default` to all the remote repositories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspected, `remote.name.push` applies only to the specified remote *`name`*.  If present, it supplies the default refspec.  For instance, doing:

```
git config remote.zorg.push refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
```

means that `git push zorg` is equivalent to `git push zorg refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master`.

However, `push.default` *does not* supply a default refspec, at least, not directly.  It can be set to one of five values:

- `nothing`: a push with no refspecs is an error
- `current`: a push with no refspecs means "push the current branch to a branch of the same name"
- `upstream` or `tracking`: a push with no refspecs means "push the current branch to its upstream"
- `simple`: like `upstream` but the upstream setting must match the branch name
- `matching`: this is the most complex; see below.

Note that `tracking` is deprecated (use `upstream` instead).  The constraint for `simple` is that if your local branch is named `xyz`, the upstream branch must also be named `xyz` on the remote.

The `matching` setting means, in effect:

- Get the listing of all the branch names from the remote (see `git ls-remote` output, look for `refs/heads/`).
- For each such branch name, if you also have a branch of the same name, add that to the list.  If not, ignore it.
- Use all of the resulting name-pairs as the refspecs.

This mode was the default in Git versions before Git 2.0, but it was pretty error-prone, so now it's not.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Is `push.default` not specific to remote repository? Does it have a lower precedence order than `remote.<name>.push`? (2) Are the following three related: `remote.<name>.push`, `push.default` and `branch.<name>.merge`? How do they work together?

Comment: (3) In `git config remote.zorg.default refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master`, should `remote.zorg.default` be `remote.zorg.push`?

Comment: (1) `push.default` applies when no *refspec* is specified on the command line. The remote can be specified or not and is irrelevant. It is indeed overridden by `remote.<name>.push`. (2) yes no: `remote.<name>.push` overrides `push.default` by specifying a refspec, but `branch.<name>.merge` only sets the *upstream* of the current branch, which only affects `simple` and `upstream` push modes, which only apply when there's no refspec.

Comment: (3) oops, yes. Will fix post.

Comment: Thanks. Can you expand your answer to explain more specifically and explicitly how remote.<name>.push, push.default and branch.<name>.merge are used? When does each applies while the other two don't? I am still not very clear from your comments.

Comment: For example, when no refspec is specified on the command line,  both push.default and remote.<name>.push may apply. When does which of them apply?

Comment: Suppose that `remote.zorg.push` is *not* set. Then `git push zorg` has no refspec, so `push.default` takes effect. On the other hand, suppose it *is* set. Then `git push zorg` has no refspec, so `remote.zorg.push` supplies the refspec, after which there's a refspec, so `push.default` is irrelevant.

Comment: When I don't specify the remote repository in command line, i.e. when I run `git push` instead of `git push zorg`, which of `remote.<name>.push` and `push.default` will apply and which will not? Is it correct that `origin` will be used as the default remote repository, so `git push` is the same as `git push origin`?

Comment: For `git push` without a remote, Git will consult the current branch's `branch.<name>.remote`. If that's not set, Git falls back to the hardcoded name `origin`.

Comment: Thanks. For `git pull` or `git fetch` without a remote argument, how is remote determined? Does it  first consider `branch.<name>.remote`, and if it is not set, then `origin`?

Comment: While `git pull` and `git push` are very different, both will use whatever the *current* branch is to determine the remote, if no remote is specified. That is, if the current branch is B, Git looks at `branch.B.remote`. If that's not set, the default here is `origin`. Now, at this point, no matter what you ran (of `git push` vs `git push xyz`), any `git push` has a remote, so Git looks up `remote.<remote>.push`. Is it set? If so, Git has a refspec. If not, Git has no refspec so `push.default` supplies the refspec. Now `git push` has both a remote and a refspec and it may proceed.

Comment: Thanks. Does `git fetch` determine remote repository in the same way as `git push` and `git pull`?

Comment: For the `remote` part, yes, fetch and push have the same rules. The old `git pull` script, however, refused to run if there was no `branch.<branch>.remote` setting. I'm not sure if the new C-coded version is the same; test it to find out.